# Get build path of local file. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a game where I read a JSON file like this:

```
private string jsonPath = "Assets/StreamingAssets/JsonChallenge.json";
```

But I realized after making the build, that th path of the Json is different. How do I get the Build path from the code? Or is there a way to savae a debug path and a build path?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Application.dataPath` like this to get the relative path:

```
jsonPath = $"{Application.dataPath}/StreamingAssets/JsonChallenge.json";
```

docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather use the [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)

> At run time, `Application.streamingAssetsPath` provides the path to the folder. Add the Asset name to `Application.streamingAssetsPath`. The built application can load the Asset at this address.

```
private string jsonPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "JsonChallenge.json");
```

The rest depends a bit on the rest of your code, your target build platform and how exactly you are trying to access this file.

Note e.g.

> It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed .apk file. These platforms return a URL. Use the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) class to access the Assets.